# Passing Class<?> parameter using Rhino

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I am trying to call a constructor for a custom collection object. This custom object takes in a parameter of type Class.

In java, this is done like this:

```
ICollection col = new PersistentCollection(ContentX.class);
```

This is my first dive into rhino, and I haven't been able to figure out quite how to pass this parameter. I figured out that "class" is a reserved word and therefor not usable.

I figured that I could get the Class from Class.forName like this:

```
importPackage(Packages.something.collections);
importPackage(Packages.something.content4);
var col = new PersistentCollection(Class.forName(ContentX));
```

But it just tosses ClassNotFoundException - with the fully qualified path something.content4.ContentX! So obviously it found the class or it wouldn't have known the path to it.

Am I doing it wrong? Sadly, I'm not in any position to change the java library right now, I need to fix the data without a new deploy.

Googling for javascript class just yields DOM/CSS problems.

Comment: How does Javascript come into the mix?

Comment: QPekka he's using Rhino (guessing here) from JDK 6 - it's packaged with the release and surprisingly easy to use

Comment: @Jörgen I just tried `var c = java.lang.Class.forName("java.util.HashMap")` from "jrunscript" and it worked just fine.

Comment: @Pointy So it is usable then. It would seem as though Rhino would be using a different classpath than the rest of the system.

Comment: I wanted to be funny but it seems that I wasn't. :P

Comment: @Jörgen I'm not sure about how Rhino loads classes; I'm sure it has something to do with the `import` statements in your code, but beyond that it's confusing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you simply need to do:

```
var col = new PersistentCollection(ContentX);
```

Or, if your class name is a string:

```
var col = new PersistentCollection(
        java.lang.Class.forName('something.content4.ContentX'));
```

Comment: Haha, you are indeed correct with this:
var col = new PersistentCollection(ContentX);
Sometimes I amaze even myself.. at how dumb I am on weekends.